# Send data before raising edge of a Clock

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, data

I'm trying to control a LED strip that has a custom protocol (developed above of I2C).

But in my tests i was successful figuring out how it works :

You set Clk to zero , you send a bit in the data line , then you set Clk to high. Based on the pixels number , i should send 16bits for each color (Red Green Blue).

I was able to generate a Clock signal at 8MHz with this code :

```
const byte Clock = 9;
const byte Data = 10;

void setup ()
{
 pinMode (Clock, OUTPUT);
 pinMode (Data, OUTPUT); 
 digitalWrite(Data, HIGH);
 TCCR1A = bit (COM1A0);
 TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (CS10);
 OCR1A =  0;    
 } 

 void loop ()
 {
 ...
 }
```

**My questions :**
How could i send data at that specific time when the clock is at zero ?

Note that using digitalWrite() function was not working due to the frequency limitation of that function.

Thanks for any helpful information.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Nick Gammon : i think i have to mention you :p

Comment: That sounds more like SPI than I2C to me. You can change the clock polarity and the sampling edge by changing the SPI mode.

Comment: The SPI sends bytes separated with a small time interval , is't possible to send multiple bits with no time interval ?

Comment: When you have a synchronous clock there is no concept of "time interval". Time is irrelevant. That's why you have a clock signal. Only the change of signal level in the clock is relevant. If you have something that requires data at precise times with no variance in the timing then you don't have a clock signal, and the communication is asynchronous (like UART).

Comment: I meant a delay between transfer of bytes

Comment: Unless you have a very very strange device then **nothing cares about delays**. SPI doesn't even *have* the concept of bytes.

Comment: That is the *whole point* of a protocol being *synchronous*. It's all *synchronised* by the clock signal. Data is read when the clock *changes* from LOW to HIGH (or the other way around for some devices). It doesn't care *when* that change happens. On that it *does* happen.

Comment: However if you gave us a clue *what* this LED strip and its protocol actually are then we would be in a better position to help you. Without that we're just pissing in the wind.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and simple clarification of how SPI works , i'm sure SPI is the choice to go with , the above code turns on all the LEDs with high intensity since data is always at 1. Now i'll try to instantiate an SPI communication with the LEDs and see how it works.

Comment: There are some strange protocols out there though. Can you *please* share the device and datasheet that you are working with?

Comment: There's no indication about the version number of the driver , i've attached pictures to the post ,i've tried to debug and test to see the Driver pinout (attached also)...

Comment: Are there no numbers on any of the chips?

Comment: Nothing , some mask is covering all the chips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night of continuous tests i figure out how to control correctly the LED strip using the following :

1- To apply any RGB value (a pixel) you have to send a compete frame of data to all the pixels. In my strip i have 12 pixels ,so to turn for example the first pixel into red , i have to send 11 zero pixels then the red pixel.

2- The delay and timing as mentioned above by @Majenko was the key, you just set the data and pulse the clk , that easy.

3- the protocol used isn't SPI or I2C , it's a custom protocol based on a custom driver developed by a private company (not a driver for general use or market , it was dev for a big wall lighting project).

```
#define setPin(b) ( (b)<8 ? PORTD |=(1<<(b)) : PORTB |=(1<<(b-8)) )
#define clrPin(b) ( (b)<8 ? PORTD &=~(1<<(b)) : PORTB &=~(1<<(b-8)) )
#define Data 7
#define Clk 9

void setup() {
pinMode(Data,OUTPUT);
pinMode(Clk, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
int i, j, k, q, r, lim_j, lim_i;
int red, green, blue;
for(k=0; k<12; k++)
{
r= k%3;
lim_j = 2 - r;
q = k/3;
lim_i = 3 - q;
Serial.print(lim_i); Serial.println(lim_j);
clrPin(Clk);
delayMicroseconds(5);
setPin(Clk);
delayMicroseconds(5);

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
  {
    if(i==lim_i && j==lim_j)
      one_pixel(1200, 0, 0);      
    else
      one_pixel(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
clrPin(Clk);
delay(1000);
}
}

int one_pixel(int red, int green, int blue)
{
rapid_serialize(red);
delayMicroseconds(5);
rapid_serialize(green);
delayMicroseconds(5);
rapid_serialize(blue);
delayMicroseconds(5);
clrPin(Clk); 
}

inline void rapid_serialize (uint16_t color) //just a copy for now , not a pointer
{   
uint16_t bit_shift = 32768;
while (bit_shift)
{
 clrPin(Clk);
 bit_shift = bit_shift>>1;
  if ((bit_shift & color) == 0)
      clrPin(Data);
  else 
      setPin(Data);
 delayMicroseconds(5);
 setPin(Clk);
 delayMicroseconds(5);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some misconceptions.

In order to work with clocked signals like in SPI, you set your data line(s) to the desired value, and then raise the clock signal from low to high. The receiving device detects the low to high transition and reads the state of the data lines.

If you did it in the other order (switch the clock signal from low to high, then set the data pin(s).) then the receiver would detect the clock rising edge and try to read the data value before it was set correctly.

With a clock line like in your setup, the communication doesn't rely on fixed timing. The clock line tells the receiver when the data is available, and you can use whatever clock timing you want (up to the max speed supported by the hardware.)

Comment: Absolutely right , i figure out the solution after a nightmare of testing.
The problem was actually with the LED driver ,it's not working with any common serial protocol.
Thanks for the help